# Different behavior when Making AJAX POST request using Jquery

Tags: jquery, post

This could be my mis-understanding but i wanted someone to explain what i miss here.

If i have the below implementation for placing POST request using Jquery, the request is not made till i execute "click" event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.post("demo_test_post.asp",
    {
      name:"Donald Duck",
      city:"Duckburg"
    },
    function(data,status){
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
  });
});
```

However if i give the anonymous function a name by defining it seperately, Then the post request is tried to send even while loading the page.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(callFunction());
});
var callFunction = function(){
    $.post("demo_test_post.asp",
    {
      name:"Donald Duck",
      city:"Duckburg"
    },
    function(data,status){
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
  };
</script>
```

Can someone explain me what i am lacking in my understanding. To me both should work the same way

Thanks for reading

Comment: You're using the result of calling the function `callFunction` instead of just referencing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's probably because you should reference the function, not call it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(callFunction); // no parenthesis
});
```

adding the parenthesis calls the function immediately and returns the result, you want to reference it only

Answer (score 0):

Try this format instead and don't forget to add `id="btn"` to your button

```
  $('#btn').click(function(event){

      var formData = {
           name:"Donald Duck",
          city:"Duckburg"
      }

    $.ajax({
                type        :   'POST'  ,
                url         :   'someurl',
                data        :   JSON.stringify(formData),
                contentTYpe :   'application/json',
                error       :   function(data,status,error){
                                    console.log(data+': '+status+': '+ error);
                                },
        success     :     function(data,status){
                  alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
        }).done(function(apiResponse){
                //Do something when done
        });
  });
```